# shopware: show downloadlink of articl after it has been bought

Tags: php, shopware

In this template,

```
/themes/Frontend/Bare/frontend/detail/tabs/description.tpl
```

a downloadlink is shown.
Now we want to show this link only after the product has been bought, namely here:

```
/themes/Frontend/Bare/frontend/account/order_item_details.tpl
```

In the `description.tpl` the variable `$sArticle.sDownloads` is available, but in `order_item_details.tpl` there is only a `$offerPosition`, which does not have the field `sDownloads`.

How is it possible to access the downloads in `order_item_details.tpl`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can listen to the event called `Shopware_Modules_Admin_GetOpenOrderData_FilterResult` to retrieve `$getOrders` which holds the data of `$offerPosition` for the template `order_item_details.tpl`.

The [Shopware Documentation](http://community.shopware.com/Shopware-4-Event-Auflistung-sAdmin-Events_detail_1072.html) tells you how to use the listener.